# Create a macro for links' href attribute in Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

In Google Tag Manager, I'd like to track with an event label in Google Analytics the clicked links `href` attribute.

On our front page there is a main Call-To-Action section that actually has 3 links. I'd like to track each one.

1) The base Google Universal Analytics (GAUA) tag already exists on all pages.

2) I created a new GAUA tag with the same tracking ID as the base tag.

3) I have specified the following:

- Track type: event
- Category: Some Category
- Action: Some Action
- Label: Href attribute

Within the event setup, when I select "New Macro" there is an option for DOM, which I thought sounded right but it requires the elements ID. On this site those links do not have an ID attribute.

I tried simply using the CSS selector for the element: `a.button.blue-button` and then, under Attribute Name I wrote "href".

But it's not working. This was for the label of the event.

How would I create a macro to record the clicked links `href` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Tag Manager does not automatically listen to clicks. You need to tell it to do that by triggering an "Event Listener" type tag.

Then you can create a rule based on the event 'gtm.linkClick' and get the href using the 'element url' predefined macro.

Answer (score 0):

You should open a Tag and defined it as "Event"
You can put whatever you want in the category/action/label. I recommend :
Category = Page url
Action = Click Url 
Label = Element text

Now you need to create a trigger that will fire every time somebody click on your call to action. I suggest you choose a trigger - "Click on links" 
choose :"some links" and define that ONLY when clickURL equale the link you want to track.